# ASP.NET Core website slow behaviour after uptime > 12 hours

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, cpu-usage, dnx

I have an web application running on the ASP.NET core (rc1, update1). It runs perfectly fine during the first few hours of uptime. However for some reason, it starts behaving abnormally slow if it is left online overnight or for a long period of time. It almost feels like the website switches to a different state.

Here are some examples of what I notice when the website goes into this slow "state".

1. The website slows down. Any operations take almost 5x the time to complete.
2. The total CPU usage is capped at 25% when performing ALL operations. Even multi-threaded ones. (This could explain why its slow.)

I have not tested this in a release version of the website. I have only seen this in the Debug version of the website, running on IISExpress in Visual Studio 2015.

I could not find anything on the web regarding this issue. Has anyone else experienced this issue before? Is there any way for me to go about resolving this issue? I have never encountered issues like this with previous versions of ASP.NET.

Comment: Are you running with the debugger attached from VS?

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci Yes

Comment: IntelliTrace might cause that. Try disabling it because it stores all the debugger events over the last 12 hours and that's a lot of data. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci Hmm i have not thought of that. Thanks for the suggestion, will try that now.